# this.value undefined message showin in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, getattribute

`changeText1(id)` showing undefined error i want value in anchor tag attribute

```js
function changeText(id) {
  id.innerHTML = "hii";
}

function changeText1(id) {
  var idq = this.value;
  id.innerHTML = idq;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
  <h1><a onclick="changeText1(this)" value="123">Click on this text!</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
<h1 ><a onclick="changeText1(this)" value="123">Click on this text!</a></h1>

<script>
function changeText(id) {
 id.innerHTML="hii";
}
function changeText1(id) {
  var idq=this.value;
  
  id.innerHTML=idq;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Can you delete your comment? It doesn't belong here.

Comment: `value` is only meaningful for input elements, not `<a>` or `<h1>`.

Comment: Git rid of that `value` in that `<a>` and get rid of `var idq = this.value;`, and change `id.innerHTML = idq;` to `id.innerHTML = '123';`, since you know the value already. Even if you don't know the value that's what `var`s are for.

Answer (score 1):

To get value from anchor tag you have to do like this

```js
function changeText1(param) {
  var val = param.getAttribute('value'); // ATTRIBUTE-NAME
  param.innerHTML = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) for an access to not standard attributes.

This works in combination with the handed over value of `this`, which is `id` in the function.

For a better understanding of the code, I suggest to rename this variable to `element`.

```js
function changeText(element) {
    element.innerHTML = "hii";
}

function changeText1(element) {
    element.innerHTML = element.getAttribute('value');
}
```

```html
<h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
<h1><a onclick="changeText1(this)" value="123">Click on this text!</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your changeText1 function with below function. Probably you cant get any attribute directly.

```
function changeText1(id) { 
    var idq = id.getAttribute("value");
    id.innerHTML = idq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` is not a valid attribute for anchor elements. If you want to store application data in the element, use a `data-*` attribute, and access it using the `dataset` property.

```js
function changeText(id) {
  id.innerHTML = "hii";
}

function changeText1(id) {
  var idq = id.dataset.value;
  id.innerHTML = idq;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
  <h1><a onclick="changeText1(this)" data-value="123">Click on this text!</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you wrote `this.value` when it should be `id.value`. But fixing that doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute called `value` for anchor tag. You can use `data` to store a value.Secondly you can use single function for both the task.

```js
   
function changeText(e) {
  // get the current element which is clicked
  let elem = e.target;
  // check if the current element have any dataset with value as a key
  if (elem.dataset.value) {
    elem.innerHTML = elem.dataset.value;
    return;
  }
  elem.innerHTML = "hii";
}
```

```html
// event is the event object
// value in data-value can be replaced by anything,but prefix data- is necessary 
<h1 onclick="changeText(event)">Click on this text!</h1>
<h1><a onclick="changeText(event)" data-value="123">Click on this text!</a></h1>
```